# Can I use one layout with 2 activities?

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-activity

Can I use one layout with 2 activities?
I have an activity called "download.java" and one called "upload.java) and ONE layout called "main_site.xml".

"download.java" is the MainActivity
It shows 2 buttons and an empty listview--> "Download", "Upload", "lv"

When I click on upload the second activity "upload" would start up which starts "main_site.xml" for second time and the listview would be filled with data.

Now I have 2 times "main_site.xml" one above the other... 
How can I just fill the listiview and not opening a "new" layout?

**OnCreate in download.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_site);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      }


    Button download = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd_download);
    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){

            connectFTP("176.28.25.46");
            listItems(); 

            } 
    });

    Button upload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cmd_upload);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v){            
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainSite.this, upload.class);
            MainSite.this.startActivity(myIntent);
            } 
    });
}
```

**OnCreate in upload.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_site);
    myPath = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.path);

    root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    getDir(root);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure on what you're trying to accomplish... You only want to change the content of the ListView and make it visible at a certain moment?

Comment: I have 2 buttons in MainActivity (Download.java) when I click on download everything works because its code is in the same activity. and with the button upload I call a new activity but i like to have the same layout... and not open it AGAIN

Comment: So yes, that is what I like. Do I have to put the full code in the same activity?

Comment: Then, you should just update the ListView's contents, with the code in the same activity.

Comment: Ok I did that and it works now :) Could you write an answer please, that I can give you an accepted answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just update the ListView's contents, with the code in the same activity.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** , you can do. There is no reason why you can't do that. If your activity design layout is same in both these activity (or as many as you have in the app) you can use the same layout.xml file in different activity.

Comment: But after that the layout.xml is opened 2 times.... I just like to update the same layouts listview and not "open" a new activity...

Answer (score 1):

Use Static array list to pass data from Upload to Download activity and just finish the Upload activity and based on conditions use the static arraylist in onResume() of Download activity

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you just have to use `<include>` as your tag, and again give an `@+id/YOUR_NAME` to reuse the same layout.